# MySql join statements order (using Eloquent ORM)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I use [Laravel Eloquent ORM](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries) in my project.
I need to duplicate a base query in order to create different queries, and as a by-product I have a problem with the order of some `JOIN` statements.

In order to simplify the problem, this query shows the problem I reach:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
JOIN C ON C.x = B.x
JOIN B ON B.y = A.y;
```

Executing this query, I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'B.x' in 'on clause'
```

I assume the reason is that when the SQL parser reaches the first join, the table `B` is not included yet. However, **the code becomes very clumsy if I switch these two lines** (see explanation at the end).

Is there any way to execute this query in this format?
Alternatively, is there any way to **inject** the second join statement before the first one using eloquent query builder?

**Why can't I switch** `JOIN` **order?**
I have a base query, which is common to different queries I need to execute:

```
SELECT * FROM A
JOIN C ON C.x = B.x
```

The key of the second `JOIN` (`B` table) depends on the final query I want to execute. For example, I might have:

```
   :
JOIN B ON B.y = A.y1
```

And in another query:

```
   :
JOIN B ON B.y = A.y2
```

In eloquent the (very simplified) code looks like:

```
$baseQuery = DB::table('A')->join('C', 'C.x', '=', 'A.x');

$query1 = (clone $baseQuery)->join('B', 'B.y', '=', 'A.y1');
$query2 = (clone $baseQuery)->join('B', 'B.y', '=', 'A.y2');
```

Comment: You really need to explain why switching join clauses would make your code clumsy! Btw, you can have a single on clause after all joins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this is a very specific problem, still I will post here my solution hopק this helps someone someday.
Again, the query I build is much bigger that in the example, so I was looking for a solution to avoid duplicating code.

The solution I found is creating a function that adds the common part of the query:

```
public function myFunc()
{
    $baseQuery = DB::table('A');

    $query1 = (clone $baseQuery)->join('B', 'B.y', '=', 'A.y1');
    $query2 = (clone $baseQuery)->join('B', 'B.y', '=', 'A.y2');

    $this->addCommonQueryPostfix($query1);
    $this->addCommonQueryPostfix($query2);
}

private function addCommonQueryPostfix(\Illuminate\Database\QueryBuilder &$query)
{
    $query->join('C', 'C.x', '=', 'B.x');
}
```

Which will create the following queries, as expected:

```
SELECT * FROM A INNER JOIN B ON B.y = A.y1 INNER JOIN C ON C.x = B.x;
SELECT * FROM A INNER JOIN B ON B.y = A.y2 INNER JOIN C ON C.x = B.x;
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT *
FROM A
JOIN B ON B.y = A.y
JOIN C ON C.x = B.x;

if you will run above query in this way it will return the same result.

Comment: As I explained, my problem is that I cannot change the order of `JOIN` statements.